# Mosquitto MQTT Broker: How to connect to external broker and subscribe to external Topics

Tags: bash, mqtt, mosquitto

I may have a basic question where I have mosquitto broker installed in my local (ubuntu). Now, I am trying to subscribe to one of the topics using following commands:

mosquitto_sub -V mqttv311 -t (topic information). Everything working fine. 
But, then I realize that how should I maintain a script which will keep on checking the connection status and take steps accordingly (in case if the connection breaks then it should try to reconnect).

Any suggestions or input here pls.

Thanks

Comment: We need a little bit more information, what are you actually doing with the data? Just promoting our to the console?

Comment: Also this is more of a bash/shell script question than a mosquitto/mqtt question. Please edit the question to show what you have already tried.